# Flutter: Is it possible to make a P2P connection with nfc_in_flutter package?

Tags: flutter, nfc, flutter-packages

I would like to send a message from an Android device to an IOS device using NFC.
I found multiple NFC packages and tried out example app from [nfc_in_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_in_flutter) but was not able to send a message between 2 phones.

Do they only support reading and writing to NFC-Tags or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS does not support Peer to Peer NFC even natively and Android has deprecated support for it in Android 10 (Android Beam).

So you are not missing something, iOS lags behind Android and only in iOS 13 supports reading/writing where as Android has supported reading/writing and Host Card Emulation for a long time.

Better to use Bluetooth or Wifi Direct